# Why does import operation works in the below react component? Is it a property of arrow function?(not considering named-export / default-export usage)

Tags: javascript, react-component, rect

Why does the below react work? As the function name in Hello.js component is Hello but it was not mentioned in main component that imported the Hello.js , Is it a property of arrow function-(if i use normal function instead of arrow function the programme show error.)

The Hello.js component :

```
import React from 'react';
const Hello =() => <h1> HELLO <h1/>
export default Hello
```

Where Hello.js component got exported/ been Called.

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './Hello'
class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
     return(
            <div>
               <MyComponent />
            <div/>
           );
      }
 }
```

Comment: You have lots of typos in your code. `hello` is not the same as `Hello`, and `form` is not the same as `from`. I'm surprised your code works at all.

Comment: Why using class components when functional components are recommend since react 16.8?

Comment: My friendly Programmers , i have used class component instant of functional component as a part of learning process. @sm3sher ,

Answer (score 2):

This is called `default export`, you can name the component as you want when you import it.

But if you are using `named export`.

Ex:

```
export const something = 'something'
```

When you import it, you need to destruct the same name.

```
import { something } from 'file/path'
```

As @Felix, mentioned, you can give to `named export` another name ( in case there are naming conflicts )

Ex:

```
import { something as somethingElse } from 'file/path'
```

For more resources.

[difference between named export and default export](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-difference-between-named-and-default-exports-in-react-2d253ca9fc22#:%7E:text=Exports%20without%20a%20default%20tag,are%20not%20React%2Dcentric%20ideas.)

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can still give it another name: `import { something as somethingElse } from 'file/path'`.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yes, thanks for mentioning that, I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning and contributing your answer , please do validate my question. In Hello.js component i have uesed a arrow function for your referance. Yes, it is a default export but at the sametime if you are using a normal function in Hello.js you import by its on function name that is Hello else it shows error.@Mina pls contribute valid answer for right questions and try out the codes and get to a conclusion . 
```import React from 'react';
function Hello(){return(<h1> HELLO </h1>)}
export default Hello```(For educational perposes use this as Hello component and see the result.)